# How to correctly import modules in pytnon?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have this code

server.py

```
from admin.users.views import users_blueprint
```

server/admin/users/forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import  StringField, SubmitField

class AddForm(FlaskForm):
   pass
```

server/admin/users/views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for
from forms import AddForm
users_blueprint = Blueprint('users_blueprint', __name__, template_folder='templates/users')
```

When I run server.py, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server/server.py", line 6, in <module>
    from admin.users.views import users_blueprint
  File "server\admin\users\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from forms import AddForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forms'
```

Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: It simply doesn't have any module named "forms". Is this forms module a custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your import statement, try:

`from .forms import AddForm`

Rationale: Python is directory-sensitive when you run code. There is no adjacent module named `forms` in your top level directory where you call server.py. The `.` tells the `server/admin/users/views.py` to import adjacently from `server/admin/users/forms.py` module.

Answer (score 1):

Since forms.py is in same folder as the calling code file (views.py) you can do:

```
from . import forms
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(str(Path('.').absolute().parent))
```

to check the parent directory when importing.

Answer (score 1):

The imports are relative to the directory in which you work when starting the python script. In this case you would need to import forms:

```py
from admin.users.forms import AddForm
```

Or use a relative import like this:

```py
from .forms import AddForm
```